# Blocking a shared controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

So I have several sites that all use the same back-end and some of the same front end functionality/controllers. However one of the sites isn't supposed to have a controller the rest of the sites do. Is there a way of still including the shared controller in the shared controllers project but block the route to it in the one site? Preferably the route to the controller should get a 404 error.

Comment: Are your controllers part of a shared assembly that these websites are using or are your controllers a separate website that others are making requests to?

Comment: Install url rewrite module and create a rule to catch this pa and rewrite it to anything, a denial page or whatever else. Do this only for this single app, in its web.config.

Comment: The controllers are part of a shared assembly among the websites.